# iCheck showing default checkboxes on page load

Tags: jquery, icheck

I am using iCheck plugin to make my checkboxes and radio buttons looks better. Also it will show the same input elements across multiple platforms. 
It is working fine except a simple thing that is while loading the page, first I am seeing the default checkbox and then only it is showing iCheck version. 
I am loading the scripts in head and iCheck is called in `document.ready`. I have the initialisation like this

```
 $('.i-checks').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
    });
```

Please suggest me which modifications needs to be done for making the iCheck boxes appear in page load itself.

Comment: Can you show part of the HTML code with those widgets?

Comment: Question is old, but I got the same problem. What I ended up to do was to hide the checkboxes and call .show() on all of them when created. With iCheck plugin, you can use the callback `ifCreated` explained here => https://github.com/fronteed/icheck

Comment: Yeah. I asked it 3 years back and forgot what I have done to make this work. Thanks for the comment. Maybe you can put this as an answer here for future reference,

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `iCheck` at the bottom of the page instead of call it in document.ready. Like this:

```
<body>
<!-- Your FORM-->
<script>
$('.i-checks').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried with that also. But it has the same result.

Comment: Call it right after the form? I don't find out any better way.